# Pointers: initialisation vs. declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14

I am a C++ noob and I am quite sure this is a stupid question, but I just do not quite understand why an error arises (does not arise) from the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() 
{
int a,*test; 

*test = &a;  // this error is clear to me, since an address cannot be 
             // asigned to an integer  


*(test = &a); // this works, which is also clear
return 0;
}
```

But why does this work too?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
int a, *test= &a;  // Why no error here?, is this to be read as:
                   // *(test=&a),too? If this is the case, why is the 
                   // priority of * here lower than in the code above?

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int *x = y;` means that `y` is the initializer for `x` (not for `*x`). It's not an assignment expression either

Comment: @M.M ok than I have to read int *test = &a as int *(test = &a)  ?

Comment: No, read it as declaring a variable called `test`, with type `int *` and initializer `&a`.

Comment: `*` `=` `&` all have different meanings in a declaration than in an expression

Comment: As you can see, declaring more than one variable on one line is best avoided.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The fundamental difference between those two lines

```
*test= &a; // 1
int a, *test= &a; // 2
```

is that the first is an expression, consisting of operator calls with the known precedence rules:

```
       operator=
          /\
        /    \
      /        \
operator*    operator&
  |             | 
 test           a
```

whereas the second is a variable declaration and initialization, and equivalent to the declaration of `int a;` followed by:

```
   int*     test    =  &a
// ^^        ^^        ^^
//type    variable    expression giving
//          name        initial value
```

Neither `operator*` nor `operator=` is even used in the second line.

The meaning of the tokens `*` and `=` (and `&` as well as `,`) is dependent on the *context* in which they appear: inside of an expression they stand for the corresponding operators, but in a declaration `*` usually appears as part of the type (meaning "pointer to") and `=` is used to mark the beginning of the (copy) initialization expression (`,` separates multiple declarations, `&` as "reference to" is also part of the type).

Comment: Good answer..  This must be the best one. I just deleted my explaination.

Comment: Plus one for using ASCII art.

Comment: @isanae indeed, my try to make it easily understandable in one sentence was too vague. I added a bit detail, is it better now?

Comment: @DanielJour Looks great!

Comment: @DanielJour thank you very much! I didn't know that there is a difference between the * in the declaration of a pointer in the dereferenceoperator *

Answer (score 3):

```
int a, *test= &a;
```

is equivalent of:

```
int a;
int* test = &a;
```

and perfectly valid as you initialize `test` which has a type of *pointer to int* with an address of variable `a` which has a type of *int*.

Comment: Rokyan but why is int a, *test; *test = &a; not valid?

Comment: @maxE because it this case you **dereference** `test` which has a type of `int*`, so you try to assign `int*` to `int` which is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing two uses for *.

In your first example, you're using it to dereference a pointer.
In the second example, you're using it to declare a "pointer to int".

So, when you use * in a declaration, it's there to say that you're declaring a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually doing an initialisation like this in first case,

```
int *test = &a;
```

**It means that,** you are initialising a pointer for which you mention `*` to tell the compiler that its a pointer.

But after initialisation doing a `*test` (*with an asterisk*) means that you are trying to access the value at the address assigned to pointer `test`.
In other words, doing an `*test` means you are getting the value of `a` because address of `a` is stored into pointer `test` which is done by just doing a `&a`.
`&` is the operator to get the address of any variable. And `*` is the operator to get the value at address.

So **initialisation** & **assignment** are inferred differently by the compiler even if the asterisk `*` is present in both the cases.

Answer (score 1):

You just hit two of the horrible language design spots: squeezing declarations into one line and reuse of `*` symbol for unrelated purposes. In this case `*` is used to declare a pointer (when it is used as part of type signature `int a,*test;`) and to deference a pointer (when it is used as a statement `*test = &a;`). The good practice would be to declare variables one at a time, to use automatic type deduction instead of type copypasting and to use dedicated `addressof` method:

```
#include <memory> // for std::addressof

int a{};
auto const p_a{::std::addressof(a)};
```

Comment: This might work for in this case, but your code actually **changes semantics**: your code uses *direct initialisation* whereas the original code uses *copy initialisation*. This has differences with regard to possible implicit conversion sequences.

Comment: @DanielJour The use of direct initialization also implies less restrictive constructor lookup (explicit constructors can be used as well). My snippet is also different in the sense that it uses list initialization, which may lead to differences with regard to possible implicit conversion sequences (`int foo = 1.0f;` - fine, `int foo = {1.0f};` - error).

Comment: Another difference here is that, in contrast to the OP's uninitialised `int a`, you explicitly default-initialise `a` to its default value, i.e. 0. And while it's good practice not to leave things uninitialised unless we can justify it (because there are cases for that) - I would say that IMO we should explicitly pass an initialiser to basic types, not just the obscure `{}`.

Comment: @underscore_d The point is to make use of `{}` mean "initialized with default content" in all situations, whether a primitive type being initialized or a class default constructor being called.

Comment: Sure, I get that, and the resulting consistency is a good goal. I just personally think that with basic types, where the value is controlled by the user, it's nicer to explicitly state that we want 0. I don't think I've ever written `int anything{}`. But I have nothing against it, except preference! It would certainly be a better reflex to have than risking use of uninitialised variables by accident.

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle difference there.

When you declare int a, *test, you're saying "declare a as an integer, and declare test as a pointer to an integer, with both of them uninitialized."

In your first example, you set *test to &a right after the declarations. That translates to: "Set the integer that test points to (the memory address) to the address of a." That will almost certainly crash because test wasn't initialized, so it would either be a null pointer or gibberish.

In the other example, int a, *test= &a translates to: "declare a as an uninitialized integer, and declare test as a pointer initialized to the address of a." That's valid. More verbosely, it translates to:

```
int a, *test;
test = &a;
```